# Cannot connect to phpMyAdmin database using MAMP Server

Tags: php, database, authentication, server

I am trying to create a login system on my website but I can't connect the database to my server (Error: localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTP ERROR 500). I am using MAMP server.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$host="localhost:3306";
$user="root";
$pass="root";

$db_name="MyDatabase";

mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Error in connecting to the mysql server!");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Error in selecting the database!");

?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try to remove :3306

Comment: Also, you are using `mysql_select_db ` where you should be using `mysqli_select_db `

Comment: Thank you @gmc. I am having this error now: "Error in selecting the database!"

Comment: Thank you @Yolo.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last 2 lines by these:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Error in connecting to the mysql server!");
mysqli_select_db($link, $db_name) or die("Error in selecting the database!");
```

Comment: I am having the same error: (Error: localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTP ERROR 500)

Comment: But are you sure that the error is in that piece of code?

Comment: These are all the files that I am using to set up my login system: https:// we.tl/guZIjWHYoI